# Python if-else function: Why does the output ignore the else line

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

I'm just learning python and I don't understand why the else line doesn't work.

The output of the script always gives me the if line and not the else line no matter the size of "count" :

```
def donuts(count):
     if count>=10: print 'Number of donuts: many'
     else: print 'Number of donuts: ' + `count` 
count = raw_input("Number of donuts: ")
donuts(count)
raw_input("press<enter>")
```

Comment: You're comparing an integer with string.

Comment: Perhaps try calling donuts(int(count)).  You may be comparing a string to an int